# CSS pseudo class with navigation bar push another element below down

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a navigation bar, I make it a pseudo class after to make a line below when hover it. It works fine for the navigation bar but it push down another element when it appears and after I don't hover it, it disappears and that element push up. How can I solve this problem or Is there any way I can do with the nav like this without pseudo class?
Here is my code. Thank you for your help.

```css
.navbar__list {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

.navbar__item {
  padding: 5px;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar__item:hover:after {
  color: black;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul class="navbar__list">
    <li class="navbar__item">About</li>
    <li class="navbar__item">Careers</li>
    <li class="navbar__item">Events</li>
    <li class="navbar__item">Products</li>
    <li class="navbar__item">Support</li>
  </ul>
  <p>Something will be push</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the 'pseudo class' by default. but hide it.
And show it when you hover.

```css
.navbar__list {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

.navbar__item {
  padding: 5px;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar__item:after {  /*  changed  */
  color: black;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  visibility:hidden; /*  Added  */
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}


/*  Added  */
.navbar__item:hover:after {
  visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul class="navbar__list">
    <li class="navbar__item">About</li>
    <li class="navbar__item">Careers</li>
    <li class="navbar__item">Events</li>
    <li class="navbar__item">Products</li>
    <li class="navbar__item">Support</li>
  </ul>
  <p>Something will be push</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @Cattttt check this bro.